# Glide doesn't work ? This is the error:

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

I am developing an app that show all album cover images of the songs.
So I am using glide for loading and caching images and to avoid OutofMemoryError.

This is my getView method in the AlbumAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RelativeLayout albumsLay = (RelativeLayout)songInf.inflate
            (R.layout.album_layout, parent, false);
    ImageView coverView = (ImageView)albumsLay.findViewById(R.id.song_cover);

    //get song using position
    Song currSong = songs.get(position);

    if (Drawable.createFromPath(currSong.getCover()) != null) {
        Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(currSong.getCover());
                    Glide.with(this).load(img).into(coverView);

    }

    albumsLay.setTag(position);
    return albumsLay;
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error:(77, 18) error: no suitable method found for with(AlbumAdapter)
method Glide.with(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument AlbumAdapter cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.Fragment by method invocation conversion)
method Glide.with(android.app.Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument AlbumAdapter cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment by method invocation conversion)
method Glide.with(FragmentActivity) is not applicable
(actual argument AlbumAdapter cannot be converted to FragmentActivity by method invocation conversion)
method Glide.with(Activity) is not applicable
(actual argument AlbumAdapter cannot be converted to Activity by method invocation conversion)
method Glide.with(Context) is not applicable
(actual argument AlbumAdapter cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: post your glide configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass context with `Glide`

```
Glide.with(this) // will not work
```

Pass context from your `Activity/Fragment` to `AlbumAdapter`

```
Context mContext;
public AlbumAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}
```

And use that context with `Glide`

```
Glide.with(mContext)
```

if you have `Activity` then you need to use `new AlbumAdapter(ActivityName.this)` and for `Fragment` you need to use `new AlbumAdapter(getActivity())`

Comment: It works thanks. But I get this other error: 
11-11 11:05:55.866  11120-11120/com.xrobot.andrew.musicalbumsE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.xrobot.andrew.musicalbums, PID: 11120
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available

Answer (score 0):

For updated version of glide,

```
RequestManager manager = Glide.with(imageView);

manager.load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```